# How do I select tags using a regex?

Tags: ruby, xml, regex, xpath, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to parse an XML file. I need to get elements with the tag name starting with a pattern followed by a numeric id.

Here is my code:

```
doc.css('*').each do |e|
  if e.name =~ /ID_*/
    puts e.name
  end
end
```

The result is:

```
ID_211850
ID_213811
ID_382621
...
```

I want to know if there are more effective ways to select the elements using either CSS or XPath? I searched Google and Stack Overflow, but most of the code is for the attribute pattern, while I need to grab the element using the pattern of the tag itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XPath:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml_string = <<HERE
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <ID_1>a</ID_1>
  <ID_2>b</ID_2>
  <ID_3>c</ID_3>
  <ID_4>d</ID_4>
  <XY_5>e</XY_5>
  <XY_6>f</XY_6>
</root>
HERE

doc = Nokogiri.parse(xml_string)
p doc.xpath('.//*[starts-with(local-name(), "ID_")]').map(&:text)
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

or:

```
p doc.css('*[name()^="ID_"]').map(&:text)
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: Humm.. I was wrong..I am wondering if really CSS selectors don't have such ability... :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit, I added an `css` method version. But I'm not sure `name()` is the standard CSS selector.

Comment: Thank you very much(*+1*)!! I should stop searching now.. :) But that corresponds to my one also.. I think,which I deleted earlier

Comment: @ArupRakshit, `()` here make a difference. :)  I'm still searching documentation for `name()`.

Comment: Thank you for the css method